# Integrating google analytics into iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics

I'm following the instructions on here to integrate google analytics into my app: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift#get-config

I'm at the point where I need to initialize analytics for my app. I've added this code in my AppDelegate.swift file:

```
import UIKit
import <Google/Analytics.h>

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:[NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        **// Configure tracker from GoogleService-Info.plist.
        NSError *configureError;
        [[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError:&configureError];
        NSAssert(!configureError, @"Error configuring Google services: %@", configureError);

        // Optional: configure GAI options.
        GAI *gai = [GAI sharedInstance];
        gai.trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;  // report uncaught exceptions
        gai.logger.logLevel = kGAILogLevelVerbose;  // remove before app release**

    }
```

I'm getting the following error messages.

1. For my `import <Google/Analytics.h>` line, I'm getting this message:'Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'.
2. For the rest of the code I'm getting several errors, although I simply copied the code in the tutorial into my file. See my screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fpQ5.png)

Comment: You can't put objective-c code in your swift file

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this issue since you're in a Swift project. You'll need to create an Objective-C bridging header, and add the import statement there. Afterwards, everything should work properly. Check out this SO answer for more details:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24005242/1784384

Comment: Thanks for the response. I created Objective-C File as Header and added import <Google/Analytics.h> to the m file. Now I'm getting an error message on the Objective-CBridgingHeader.m file that says:'Expected identified or '('.  Additionally, I'm still seeing the same errors on my AppDelegate.swift file from the code that I had pasted in before.

Comment: The bridging header file should be a .h file; make sure you're putting it in there.

Also: your code is failing in your AppDelegate because you pasted Objective-C code in there. In your link on Google's website, there's a box that allows you to change it to Swift example code. Do that and you should be golden!

Comment: Okay, so I moved this line of code 'import <Google/Analytics.h>' to my .h file. I also updated the code in my AppDelegate file. Initially I had selected the Swift radio button on the tutorial but I guess it switched over or I re-opened a new page without noticing. In any case, things are looking better. I'm not seeing an error messages.

Comment: I meant to say that I added the import code to my Bridging-Header.h file. Do I have to create a second .h file as indicated in the stackoverflow response(http://stackoverflow.com/a/24005242/1784384) that you sent me?

Comment: I'm having a tough time envisioning what you'er asking. But you should be able to delete the .m and .h file you created, and leave the bridging header. The bridging header is automatically created when you add Obj-C code, but doesn't detect it when you use Cocoapods. That's why you have to go through this weird process.

Comment: I have one .m file and I have my .h file which is called Bridging-Header.h. You're saying that I should remove my .m file and keep my Bridging-Header.h file which has this line of code: import <Google/Analytics.h>.

Comment: What is your .m file called?